# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::define()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am using [Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization) in Laravel 5.6

But getting this Error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::define()

How can I resolve this problem?

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];
```

and in boot:

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
        $this->registerPolicies();

        $gate->define('isAdmin', function ($user){
            return $user->role == 1;
        });
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `$gate->define` with `Gate::define`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved!

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('isAdmin', function ($user) {
        return $user->role == 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what was the problem?

Comment: I didn't add the Gate class.